# Linux Module - I/O Memory Register read/write hangs the system

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am trying to read/write to a I/O Memory Register of a platform device but the system hangs as soon as it goes to the line where read/write is performed.

I was able to check the following:

- request_mem_region returns OK
- the correct physical addr was requested (ioremap is OK)
- a valid logical address is returned; used this to read the
  register; ioread32(logical_addr)

I am quite new to the linux kernel, is there a way that the I/O registers are disabled?
I checked /proc/iomem, and the memory region that I wish to access appears in the list.

Where to go from here?

Comment: On what kind of hardware are you trying to perform this iomap/ioread ? Maybe the hardware needs some prior initialization ?

Comment: It is a ARMv6 System-on-Chip. I am trying to write a loadable module for a platform device. (a media codec hardware assist component). I already checked the initialization, I'll check again. Thanks! Is there a way to disable/enable I/O Memory Registers on the linux kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Thank you for your response Longfield.
I forgot to check the name used by the driver. It didn't match the device name being registered. They should match.